# Function pointers - why, when I can do without?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers

Disclaimer: I've read countless other articles on this topic and I still don't get them. Example: why do this:

```
void func(int a, void (*callback)(int))
{
    /* do something with a and callback */
    callback(3);
}

void pointme(int b)
{
    /* do something with b */
}

int main()
{
    void (*pf)(int);
    pf = &pointme;
    func(10, pf);
}
```

when I can simply do this:

```
void func(int a)
{
    pointme(3);
    /* do something with a*/
}

void pointme(int b)
{
    /* do something with b */
}

int main()
{
    func(10);
}
```

??? I really don't get it. Any help would be super-appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: There's no point. Particularly since your first version won't compile

Comment: One reason to use function pointers is for when you do not know what function will get called at compile time. For example, imagine a generic sorting function - it knows the algorithm to perform the sort, but it does not understand the data nor how to compare the data to determine proper order. A data-specific function pointer can be provided to allow the generic sort to serve as an opaque library.

Comment: if by "it can't compile" you mean my program is just a rough outline with dummy-codeblocks, yes, I agree, it's for example purposes. But if I've missed some other important feature in my code, please tell me where so that I can correct it. It's very possible, as I've been preparing for an interview for the past 4 days almost non-stop, so my mind is a mess right now.

Comment: Pick either C or C++, they aren't the same. For example, in C++ you should use `std::function`.

Comment: @Otringal `func(10, pf(3));` will not compile because the second parameter to `func()` is a function pointer, and `pf(3)` is not. You could call `func(10, pf);` (but you cannot pass the `3` in under your current function signature).

Comment: @mah why is that? Here's my initial website from where I got the ideas: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html
Notice is explains the same things as you guys and I'm still not able to understand lol :)

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski thanks, I've added the correction!

Comment: @Otringal just like you can call `pointme(3)`, you can call `pf(3)` (after making `pf` point to the function. A function pointer is used like any function name -- in fact, function names are effectively function pointers. The syntax you're familiar with for calling functions is the same as for using function pointers. You could even, for example, call `func(10, pointme);` -- skipping the local function pointer variable completely.

Comment: @Otringal -- Instead of reading articles, how about real code:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort  Look at the last parameter.  How about Windows OS?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Look at the first parameter.  That function is called for every window that is encountered.  That function is **your** function called by Windows.  How did it do that?  Did Bill Gates read your mind? :)

Comment: Look at qsort. You can change how you sort something based on changing the function. You may not own the function, your caller does.

Comment: @RobertJacobs: but if I don't own the function, than how can I send a function pointer, since I can't point to that function anyway since I don't own it??? Cause I can't just send in an uninitialized function pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: The Microsoft article is completely above my level, I did not make heads or tail of it. However, I've seen the qsort example everywhere and my question is: why not just pass a -1, 0 or 1 to qsort, telling it what type of sorting we want, rather than pointing an entire function that must be called only to return the same thing??

Comment: Lets say you write qsort. qsort doesn't own the function to compare elements. Its caller does. If you are calling a library, you may need to write this function. What if a function doesn't know what this function should do, but it knows when it should do it. It uses a function pointer to allow another author to decide what should be done.

Comment: About qsort. Its more general than that. a structure may have 10 elements and you may only want to sort on 3 of them. They could be ints, doubles or strings. qsort doesn't know what the structure looks like at all. It only know the number of bytes to move around. The function know the entire structure and what fields you care about sorting and ascending/descending in each fields case. 0,-1,0 doesn't cut it.

Comment: @RobertJacobs: _What if a function doesn't know what this function should do, but it knows when it should do it. It uses a function pointer to allow another author to decide what should be done._ Now THAT really helped me much more!!! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Just as a funny note: Due to how C (and probably C++) handle expressions consisting only of an identifier bound to a function, every time you call a function (like `foo()`) you're actually calling via the corresponding function pointer: `(&foo)()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> when I can simply do this [...]

That's correct, you should call the function directly if you can. However, there are situations when you cannot make a direct call, because the function that you are trying to call does not exist in *your* code. Of course, the function will be there in the finished program, but in many situations you would develop a library that interacts with other people's code, and needs to compile by itself.

In addition, there are situations when you can call the function directly, but you do not want to do it to avoid code repetition.

This is when function pointers come in handy: the caller can tell *your* function which of *his* functions to call.

Consider designing a threading library that lets users run their functions in parallel. This library cannot make direct references to user code, for two reasons:

- Your code has no idea which functions the users are going to run concurrently, and
- You do not want to write a separate function for each kind of function that your users may decide to pass to your library.

Comment: if it doesn't exist in my code, then wouldn't the same problem arise with a function pointer as well? Cause it points to a function that's not in my code, therefore I still can't compile my standalone project. Also, how are function pointers removing repetitions? Cause the normal way in which I'd call a function just takes one function call, the same goes for accessing the function pointer. I mean, I still have to *do it*

Comment: @Otringal A function pointer is still a pointer.  There are no magical powers it has over other pointers.  So just like other pointers are passed to the library, a function pointer can be passed to the library.

Comment: After reading your later edit, I've finally found an answer that satisfies MY way of thinking (all other answers are still not very relevant as far as my poor knowledge can make use of them). To sum up: even though I can hard-code a function call within another function's body, it's impossible to have a dummy/wild-card function placeholder in case I want to pass another function in there. It's as though function pointers allow me NOT to overload my "mother" function with all possible combinations of "to-be-called" functions, thus creating a generic function pointer that can later be changed.

Comment: @Otringal A function being called may not exist in your code, but it needs to exist in the code of someone calling your function. Your code will compile with a function pointer properly declared.

Comment: @Otringal Your second comment is an explanation of the situation when you can make a call, but you don't want to hard-code it. The situation when you cannot hardcode a call arises only when you develop code in cooperation with someone else whose code you cannot access, or you partition your code on purpose into a reusable library that calls functions by pointer and the rest of the application that passes function pointers to your reusable library.

Comment: @Otringal "*all other answers are still not very relevant as far as my poor knowledge can make use of them)*" --  Because you're probably thinking of code being all your own, instead of the "library / user" model.  A library writer has no idea what the name of a user's function will be, but the library does have the ability to call this user function.  How does the library accomplish this feat, i.e. call a function without a name?  The user passes a pointer to the function ,stores this pointer somewhere, and at the appropriate time, calls the function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: thanks!!! you've added a bit more light on my dark views of this matter :) I think this only works mostly with libraries, right?? As I can compile something with a dummy pointer to an unknown function, but I cannot link and execute actual code, right? Also, I'm still a bit unclear as why would the library writer expect a function of unknown name from the user, when you can pretty much always request the parameters that would return from that function anyway and bypass the whole problem of not knowing the user's function name..

Comment: @Otringal pretend I am providing you with a library to perform a sort. I am not providing you source code to that library (or if I am, you have reasons which prevent you from making _any_ changes to it at all). My library doesn't know how to compare, for example, your structured data -- which is a bit of a problem because I must be able to compare the data in order to sort it. To resolve this, you provide me access to your function. Since you cannot rewrite my code, we must agree that I receive a pointer to your function, and I can call your function through that pointer.

Comment: Why do you say you can't link if you use function pointers?  You can link with no problems.  The linker looks for actual function **names** that your application calls, not function pointers.  If at runtime, you don't *initialize* or you don't assign to those functions (at some point) the address of a function, and you attempted a call, then you get the same fate that would happen if you declared a "regular" pointer and attempted to dereference it without initializing it.  Most likely, crash and burn.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: you're right, I got caught in the syntax and because I could use function pointers pretty much like function names, I've made the wrong assumption that the linker will look for what that pointer points to, see that it points to nothing and then crash. Also, thanks for yet another helpful example. Basically I didn't understand the whole concept cause I was thinking from the user's perspective, which can pretty much always avoid function pointers. But library writers indeed need a way to receive unknown functions from the library users.

Comment: @Otringal -- Think of a design where you can change the behavior of a certain aspect of a library without rewriting the library.  How would you do that?  -- in other words a "plugin" type of a system.  This runtime flexibility can only be achieved using function pointers (or since this is C++, function objects, functors, as well as function pointers).  As to crash, that would happen if you call via function pointer, and the pointer points to garbage, no different than if you had a regular pointer that pointed to garbage and you tried to use it.

Answer (score 2):

In C, function pointers allow you to do the following:

- Create plug-in architectures;
- Create "generic" functions and data structures;

and a few others that I'm not going to go into.

**Plug-ins**

If you've used any sort of image editor, audio editor, browser, etc., you've probably used some kind of plug-in; that is, some little piece of code that wasn't part of the original application, but is provided by a third-party library, allowing you to *add new functionality* to the app without having to upgrade or rebuild. This is done by packaging code into *shared* or *dynamically linked* libraries (`.dll` files on Windows, `.so` files on Linux).  The program can load the contents of that file *at runtime*, then execute functions contained within that library.

A real-world example would take more space and time than we have, but here's
a toy program and library that illustrate the concept:

```
/**
 * lib1.c
 *
 * Provides functions that are called by another program
 */
#include <stdio.h>

static char *names[] = {"func1", "func2", NULL};

char **getNames( void ) { return names; }
void func1( void )      { printf( "called func1\n" ); }
void func2( void )      { printf( "called func2\n" ); }
```

The `getNames` function basically gives me an inventory of what functions are available in the library for me to call (there are about a thousand better ways to do this, but you should get the point).

To build this into a shared library, I do the following:

```
gcc -o lib1.so -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -fPIC -shared lib1.c
```

This creates the shared library file `lib1.so`.

Now I add a simple driver:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main( void )
{
  /**
   * Open the shared library file
   */
  void *lib1handle = dlopen( "lib1.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL );

  /**
   * Load the "getNames" function into the current process space
   */
  char **(*libGetNames)( void ) =  dlsym( lib1handle, "getNames" );
  if ( libGetNames )
  {
    /**
     * call the "getNames" function in the shared library
     */
    char **names = libGetNames();
    while ( names && *names)
    {
      printf( "calling %s\n", *names );
      /**
       * Load each named function into the current process space
       * and execute it
       */
      void (*func)(void) =  dlsym( lib1handle, *names++ );
      if ( func )
        func();
    }
  }
  dlclose( lib1handle );
  return 0;
}
```

I built this code as follows:

```
gcc -o main -std=c99 -Wall -Werror main.c -ldl
```

Note that the `lib1.so` file isn't part of the build command; the `main` program *doesn't know* about that library code until it is run.

You'll also have to put the current directory in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, otherwise `dlopen` won't find the library:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/dynlib: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

All this code does is get the list of function names via the `getNames` function in the library, then it loads and executes each function in the library in turn.  The `libGetNames` function pointer will point to the `getNames` function in the library, and the `func` function pointer will point to each of `func1` and `func2` in turn.  When run, it produces the following output:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/dynlib: ./main
calling func1
called func1
calling func2
called func2
```

Exciting, right?  But this is pretty much how apps like Photoshop and Audacity and others allow you to extend their functionality without having to upgrade or rebuild or whatever; you just download the right library, put it in the right place, and the app will load the contents of that library and make that code available to you.

Sure, you could statically link the library with `main` and call the functions directly, but the beauty of the shared library concept is that it allows you to add new functions to `main` *without having to touch `main` itself*.

**"Generic" Functions and Data Structures**

The canonical example of a "generic" function in C is the `qsort` function.  Using `qsort`, you can sort arrays of any type; all you have to do is provide a function that does the actual comparison of elements in the array.  Again, a stupid example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpInt( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
  const int *l = lhs, *r = rhs;
  return *l - *r;
}

int cmpFloat( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
  const float *l = lhs, *r = rhs;
  return *l - *r;
}

char *fmtInt( char *buffer, size_t bufsize, const void *value )
{
  const int *v = value;
  sprintf( buffer, "%*d", (int) bufsize, *v );
  return buffer;
}

char *fmtFloat( char *buffer, size_t bufsize, const void *value )
{
  const float  *v = value;
  sprintf( buffer, "%*.*f", (int) bufsize, 2, *v );
  return buffer;
}

void display( const void *data, size_t count, size_t size, char *(*fmt)(char *, size_t, const void *))
{
  const char *d = data;
  char buffer[10];
  printf( "{%s", fmt( buffer, sizeof buffer, &d[0] ));
  for ( size_t i = size; i < count * size; i += size )
    printf( ", %s", fmt( buffer, sizeof buffer, &d[i] ));
  printf( "}\n" );
}

int main( void )
{
  int   iarr[] = {9, 100, 53, 99, 4, 29, 44};
  float farr[] = {9, 100, 54, 99, 4, 29, 44};

  printf( "iarr before sort: " );
  display( iarr, sizeof iarr / sizeof *iarr, sizeof *iarr, fmtInt );
  qsort( iarr, sizeof iarr / sizeof *iarr, sizeof *iarr, cmpInt );
  printf (" iarr after sort: " );
  display( iarr, sizeof iarr / sizeof *iarr, sizeof *iarr, fmtInt );

  printf( "farr before sort: " );
  display( farr, sizeof farr / sizeof *farr, sizeof *farr, fmtFloat );
  qsort( farr, sizeof farr / sizeof *farr, sizeof *farr, cmpFloat );
  printf (" farr after sort: " );
  display( farr, sizeof farr / sizeof *farr, sizeof *farr, fmtFloat );

  return 0;
}
```

Again, not very exiting - this code defines two arrays, one `int` and one `float`, displays them, sorts them, then displays them again:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/dynlib: ./sorter
iarr before sort: {         9,        100,         53,         99,          4,         29,         44}
 iarr after sort: {         4,          9,         29,         44,         53,         99,        100}
farr before sort: {      9.00,     100.00,      54.00,      99.00,       4.00,      29.00,      44.00}
 farr after sort: {      4.00,       9.00,      29.00,      44.00,      54.00,      99.00,     100.00}
```

However, I'm *decoupling* type information from the basic sorting and display logic.  `qsort` doesn't need to know the *types* of its elements, it only needs to know whether one element compares "less than" or "equal to" another.  It calls the `cmpInt` and `cmpFloat` functions to perform the actual comparison; none of the other logic requires type information.  I don't have to replicate the guts of the sorting algorithm for each different type (`sort_int`, `sort_float`, `sort_foo`); I only have to provide the right comparison function to `qsort`.

Similarly, all the `display` function is doing is printing out a comma-separated list of strings, surrounded by `{` and `}`.  It lets the `fmtInt` and `fmtFloat` worry about the details of how ints and floats are formatted.  I don't have to replicate any of the display logic for the different types.

By now you've probably noticed that I keep putting "generic" in scare quotes.  The problem is that you have to pass the *address* of everything as a `void *`, meaning you're throwing type safety out the window.  The compiler can't protect me against passing the wrong comparison or formatting function for a given array; I'll just get garbled output (or a runtime error). Languages like C++ and Java and C# provide templating capablities that allow you to write generic code yet still maintain type safety (i.e., the compiler will still be able to yell at you if you're using the wrong type).

There are other uses for function pointers, but I've already spent way too much time and energy on this answer than I should have.

Comment: wow, John Bode, can't thank you enough! That's about as deep as anyone would get with such an explanation, you truly are amazing for devoting the time in writing this huge answer post. I'm still lacking a bit of syntax understanding in your examples, but all the better cause now I can take your 2 codes step by step and research each thing I'm not familiar with, until I can fully read and understand them. It'll be quite a homework but oh boy, will it pay off! :D Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 2):

For a short simple example, check out function [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/).

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

The 4th parameter is a function pointer.

It is a function that can sort any array of any type of data, provided that the programmer (*you*) provide a much simpler function that simply compares two items and indicates which one is bigger.

Function `qsort` clearly does not know about your type of data.  And you don't need to know the complexities of sorting data quickly and efficiently.  But as long as you provide a function to do the comparison, and the standard library provides a sort routine, the two work together to accomplish a powerful task.